# ruby/rails NoMethodError? when using custom validation method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

i'v been new to ruby and rails and encountered a rather strange error:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :description, :if => require_description_presence?

    def require_description_presence?
        self.can_send_email
    end
end
```

raises

```
NoMethodError in PeopleController#index

undefined method `require_description_presence?' for #<Class:0x4c4fadc>
```

Answer (score 8):

You should pass validation method as symbol:

```
validates_presence_of :description, :if => :require_description_presence?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this even shorter and sweeter.  The `:if` clause will take an attribute just as easily.  So if can_send_email is a boolean attribute of Person, this will work:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :description, :if => :can_send_email?
end
```

No need to create another method just to check this attribute.  And if you notice the extra question mark at the end of `can_send_email`, it's because Rails lets you do that with boolean attributes.  I like it because it makes the code's purpose more clear.